# How to calculate percentage of value inside arbitrary range?

Tags: c#

Considering a list like this one where number can be totaly random:

```
 List<decimal> someNumber = new List<decimal> {400,300,200,0,-200,-300,-400 };
```

What is the formula put into range for exemple [+100% : -100%]  or in range  [+1 : -1]
to be clear same question than here but with negative and c#
[math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51509/how-to-calculate-percentage-of-value-inside-arbitrary-range)

Comment: "born" doesn't mean what you think it means, and your question is unclear.

Comment: What does "born it into range" mean?  Do you want to change (range `[400 : -400]`) `400,300,200,0,-200,-300,-400` to `100,75,50,0,-50,-75,-100` when the new range is [+100 : -100]?

Comment: yes put it into range as percentage or coeficient

Comment: I think  : borner in french = limit

Comment: You'll need to be more clear - do you want to take an existing list and re-scale it? Or create a list of truly random numbers that are within some range?

Comment: to be clear put this as percentage so 200  is 50% when the max in serie is 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I think you're trying to normalize a list to be between -1 and +1.

This takes the list and normalizes it to 0-2, then shifts the result down to -1 to +1.

```
List<decimal> someNumber = new List<decimal> { 400, 300, 200, 0, -200, -300, -400 };
var min = someNumber.Min();
var max = someNumber.Max();
var range = max - min;
var normalizedList = someNumber.Select(x => 2*(x-min)/(range) - 1).ToList();
```

C# interactive shell output:

```
> normalizedList
List<decimal>(7) { 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -0.75, -1 }
```

This works for non symmetric ranges or positive ranges too.